# how to fix jquery min js API get request syntax error

Tags: javascript, jquery

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcZhH.png)[image]

When I select the country to select the city for which I want to see the weather forecast, I get a lot of errors for jquery.min.js. There are no errors in it, I redid and inserted the string from Google to jquery many times

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON('current.city.list.json', function(data) {
    $('select').on('change', function() {
      var out = '';
      for (var key in data) {
        if (data[key].country == $('select option: selected').vall()) {
          out += `<p value="${data[key].id}">${data[key].name}</p>`;
        }
      }
      $('#city').html(out);
      $('#city p').on('click', function() {
        $get(
          "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather", {
            id: $(this).attr('value'),
            "appid": "ccb32c048e20c9231b63123395cdc52c"
          },
          function(data) {
            let out = '';
            out += 'Погода: <b>' + data.weather[0].main + '</b><br>';
            out += ' <p style="text-align:center"><img scr="https://openweathermap.org/img/w/' + data.weather[0].icon + '.png"></p>';
            out += 'Температура: <b>' + Math.round(data.min.temp - 273) + '&#176;C</b><br>';
            out += 'Влажность: <b>' + data.main.humidity + '%</b><br>';
            out += 'Давление: <b>' + Math.round(data.main.pressure * 0.00750063755419211 * 100) + 'мм.рт.ст</b><br>';
            out += 'Видимость: <b>' + (data.visibility / 1000) + 'км</b><br>'
            console.log(data.main)
            $('#weather').html(out)
          }
        )
      })
    })
  })
})
```

There are no errors in it, I redid and inserted the string from Google to jquery many times

Comment: Get rid of the space after `:` in `$('select option: selected').

Comment: You have a typo: `.vall()` should be `.val()`. And this can all be simplified to `$('select').val()`. The value of a select is the value of its selected option.

Comment: Or `$(this).val()`.

Comment: `value` is not a standard attribute for `<p>` elements. Use a `data-XXX` attribute for custom attributes.

Comment: I removed the spaces and nothing changed, it still finds a syntax error between == and $

Comment: That's a different error. The original error wasn't between `==` and `$`, it was coming from `$('select option: selected')` itself.

Comment: https://github.com/lilbodyn/Front-end/tree/front-end/API/Rest%20API/weather

Comment: It still has a space between `option` and `:selected`.

Comment: And what I need to change? Thank u). I’m 16 years old and I from Ukraine. 
I'm just learning this and I'm still in school

Comment: Change `$('select option: selected').val()` to `$(this).val()`

Comment: if (data[key].country==$('select option:selected').val()){
                out+= `<p data-XXX="${data[key].id}">${data[key].name}</p>`;
            } 
Like this?

Comment: Ok, one moment pls

Comment: But I have new problems((((((

Comment: I added a new photo

Comment: `$get` should be `$.get` or `$.getJSON`

Comment: Yes, thank u. I made this.